# Determination of injectivity and sujectivity of linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

$T$ is a linear map $$T : P_2(\Bbb R)\to P_3(\Bbb R)$$ defined by $$T(f(x)) = xf(x) + f′(x).$$  $P_i$ denotes polynomials with degree less than or equal to $i$.
I tried to determine whether $T$ is surjective or injective. I first tried to find the kernel of $T$, and then come up with the following. 
$f'(x)=-xf(x)$ , this equation has solution $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}k e^{-x^2}$ for any $k \in \mathbb{R}$. But $f$ is not a polynomial and then I am stuck.Can anyone help?

Comment: To show that there are no polynomials $P$ satisfying $xP+P'=0$ you can also observe that the degree of $xP+P'$ is at least $1$, unless $P=0$. It is easier than solving the differential equation (and it is also  more algebraic in nature).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You showed that there are no polynomials satisfying $xf+f'=0$, hence $\ker T =\{0\}$. This guarantees that $T$ is injective.

Now, for surjectivity. What is is the dimension of $P_2$  and of $\ker T$? Is there a formula that you can apply to obtain the dimension of $im (T)$? When you find this dimension and compare with the dimension of $P_3$, wha can you conclude?

Answer (score 2):

You can do **surjectivity** also like that. Take any polynomial $p(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$, we have to find $f(x) = ex^2+fx+g$ such that:

$$ xf(x)+f'(x) = p(x)$$
so

$$ex^3+fx^2+(g +2e)x+f = ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$$

so $e=a$, $f=b$, $g+2e =c$ and $f=d$.

So if $b\ne d$ then $p(x)$ is not in the range.

**Also we can see injectivity:**

$$T(ex^2+fx+g) = ex^3+fx^2+(g +2e)x+f$$ Thus if $$T(ex^2+fx+g)= T(e'x^2+f'x+g')$$
we get, by comparing the coefficients $e=e'$, $f=f'$ and $g=g'$ and thus it is injective.

Answer (score 2):

This is why you learn about matrices and bases and the like. There is a straightforward, simple solution method:

- Choose a basis for both vector spaces
- Write down the matrix that expresses the linear transformation
- Phrase the given question in terms of properties of this matrix
- Use your tools for doing computations with matrices

Comment: The key to this problem is rank-nullity dimension formula.This indeed simplifies the problem a lot.

Comment: It is clearly easier without matrices. So this is not why you learn about matrices.